# Подключение Google Fonts

Tags: css, шрифты, google-fonts

[Подключил](http://cl46839.tmweb.ru/index.php?id=2) шрифты Google к стилям:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300&subset=cyrillic-ext,cyrillic);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700&subset=cyrillic-ext,cyrillic);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script&subset=cyrillic);
```

Но почему-то в Ubuntu буквы "Б", "Ф", "Й" отображаются жирным начертанием. Ощущение, что что-то не так со шрифтами, вот только я никак не пойму — что?

P.S.

1. Редактор Хэшкод неправильно формирует ссылки в коде этого вопроса и в конце `);` оставляет как часть ссылки.
2. В ответ на ссылку...

...из первого `@import` приходит:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTZ1r3JsPcQLi8jytr04NNhU.woff) format('woff');
}
```

...из второго:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Ubuntu'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ubuntu/v4/5mBhVjyLdKpTbwI2zOPjQA.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Ubuntu Bold'), local('Ubuntu-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ubuntu/v4/oxrPYIm05JrY_0rFIEQ_oT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

...из третьего:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Marck Script';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Marck Script'), local('MarckScript-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/marckscript/v4/O_D1NAZVOFOobLbVtW3bcoraN7vELC11_xip9Rz-hMs.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: Все ссылки рабочие и мне кажется что для решения проблемы надо поменять порядок подключения и ...umbuntu/v4/... (короче @import #2) поставить последним но это я так, пусть гуру типа @Deonis разбираются...

Answer (score 1):

Видимо так шрифты прорисовываются. Попробуйте изменить зум браузера и увидите, что при увеличенном масштабе они правильно выглядят.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но неужели так и должно быть?? Выглядит отвратительно...

Comment: По личному опыту - шрифты гугл отображаются в разных браузерах, а порой, и в одних и тех же браузерах, но в разных ОС по разному. Это необходимо иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 0):

Тут доходчиво про шрифты и варианты их подключения. Разбирается настройка , основные свойства шрифтов. Подключение через @fontface/googlefonts https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwA0BN5RgB0&t=7s

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]